# Woocommerce include element in products-only list page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to include sidebar only in product list page. I mean last child page where there is no categories or subcategories to select, only products. Problem is I can't find where can I include my code for that.

There is `content-product.php` file that generate list of products (without categories or subcategories), but loop starts and ends in different files (`loop-start.php` and `loop-end.php`) and are used both for products-only loop (`content-product.php`) and categories/subcategories loop (`content-product-cat.php`).

I found some [woocommerce conditional tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) for checking in which page you are in, but as I can understand, there is no possibility to seperate products-only list page from categories/subcategories list page with these functions.

Maybe someone had to do something similar before and would be so kind to shere knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce does have a way of telling if there are products to be shown on the page. It does that very check in archive-content.php ( https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php ).
Basically, when you're about to output the sidebar, add a check to see if there are/were any posts on the page. Woocommerce itself can use have_posts(), but since you'll probably want to use your sidebar after the Loop, you'll have to do it manually:

```
global $wp_query;
if ( $wp_query->post_count > 0 ) ...
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I haven't thought, that categories and subcategories won't be counted as posts.